# Changing value of a python variable whose name is in a string

Tags: python, list, variables, dictionary

Before you say to use a dictionary, I want to change the value of the actual variable.

This is what happens with the standard dict strategy: (Note that I'm not necessarily using a list, the value could be a complex class type or just a regular int)

```
>>> dict = {}
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> dict["x"] = x
>>> x
[1, 2, 3]
>>> dict["x"]
[1, 2, 3]
>>> dict["x"] = [4,5,6]
>>> dict["x"]
[4, 5, 6]
>>> x
[1, 2, 3]
>>>
```

Anyone know a way to do this so that the actual contents of x are changed as well? copy.deepcopy doesn't do the trick either. (as in 'dict["x"] = copy.deepcopy(x)')

Comment: You have not convinced me that you don't need a dictionary.

Comment: Why do you want to access variables by their names? See [Keep data out of variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html)

Comment: @LevLevitsky I would like x to contain [4,5,6] after my assignment.

Comment: But why do you want to access a variable `x` using a string? Why not just continue to access it as `dict["x"]`?

Comment: @DavidRobinson I happen to work with software that has a large dataset that I need to manipulate with python. I can only access them by their names. Can't provide any more details I'm afraid. 

To answer your second question, the variable x has been initialized previously and there are dependencies in other parts of the system that require x to reflect the changes.

Comment: Keeping a large dataset as Python variables, where you access them by their Python names, isn't a good strategy. It would be much better to keep them within a dictionary or other structure.

Comment: They're stored in some class hierarchy that I have no influence over.

Comment: I don't own the code, can't refactor it.

Comment: You say that there are dependencies in other parts of the system that have already initialized `x`, but also that `x` can be an int. This is dangerous: anywhere x has already been used you can't change it in this way. You could give the global `x` a new value, but that gets you into more trouble.

Comment: Yeah, I wish it was set up in a different way.

Answer (score 4):

Use slice assignment:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> d['x'] = x
>>> d['x'][:] = [4, 5, 6]
>>> x
[4, 5, 6]
>>> d['x']
[4, 5, 6]
```

For other data types make sure you modify them in-place instead of assigning them to new variables. Note that for immutable data types like int, strings etc there are no in-place operations available.

Comment: This won't work for the OP: `(Note that I'm not necessarily using a list, the value could be a complex class type or just a regular int)`.

Comment: Sure, but the *principle* is the same -- modify the data in-place, don't overwrite it.

Comment: @ThaneBrimhall: there's no way to modify an int in place.

Comment: Actually, it complains if I'm using longs, for example. (" 'long' object does not support item assignment")

Comment: There's no way to reference the same `int` in multiple places either.

Comment: @ThaneBrimhall: But the value of an `int` can be changed, (`x = 1`, or `exec("%s = 1" % varname)` I suppose) which is presumably what the OP wants (even though it's a bad idea).

Comment: @Inbl It is impossible to update all the references of a long/int by just by updating any one of the references, all operations on them return a new object. About the error: slice assignment is a list specific operation, so it won't work with longs.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Yes, I know. I just keep hoping the OP is mistaken about what he/she wants and it's only an issue for mutable types. ;)

Comment: Why is exec a bad idea? (Just curious)

Answer (score 2):

this is a horrible idea and stinks of horrible code smell ... dont do this you **need to refactor the code** to be sensible .... this is a terrible idea but if you want

```
mutables = {
"x":x,"y":y,"Z":Z #make sure the dict key is exactly the same as var name
}

mutables['x'] = [5,6,7]
for k,v in mutables.items():
    globals()[k] = v
```

note that you will need to be in the same global scope as the original variables

Comment: Yeah I know it's a bad situation, I wish the owners of the code would refactor it because I don't have permission to change it.